# Matching PK from different tables to a composite PK FK in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, composite-primary-key

[image: DB Model]

The image reflects the expected result. I am trying to define the relation between *product_translation* Table composite primary keys and the PK in Tables *product* and *language* using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Management Studio. As I try to define a relation between, say, product_translation composite PKs and product PK I get an error:

> Both sides of a relationships must have same number of columns

That makes sense but wizard does not allow me to choose the two PKs needed to match the composite PK **from two different tables**, which is present case.

As all three tables are already set up, is there an ALTER statement allowing me to set required relations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Delete the table product_translation.. Please make sure that you do not have any data in there first. Then add the code as follows.

CREATE TABLE [product_translation]
(
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( product_non_transid, language_id),
  FOREIGN KEY ( product_non_transid) REFERENCES [Product] ( Id ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION  ON DELETE  CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY ( language_id) REFERENCES [language] ( Id ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION  ON DELETE  CASCADE,
product_name Varchar2(100),
description Varchar2(500)
)

Comment: Thanks Jack, that worked as intended. I just had to slightly modify the query as both PK had to be created before being assigned. 
CREATE TABLE [product_translation] (product_non_transid int, language_id int, PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ...

Comment: @Luke I am glad I could help. Cheers Buddy !